# Format JSON to contain a list from mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I asked this a while ago but I didn't have anything set up. Now I have more of a grasp on what I need to do.

I have an SQL query that returns the following result:

```
1   Baked Apple Apple
2   Seafood Rice Balls  Hylian Rice
2   Seafood Rice Balls  Hyrule Bass
```

Which is generated from a stored procedure that just joins a food table, a food-ingredient many-many table, and the ingredients table.

```
SELECT F.Id, F.Name 'Dish', I.Name 'Ingredient' FROM `Food` F
JOIN Food_Ingredients FI ON F.Id = FI.`FoodId`
JOIN Ingredients I ON FI.`IngredientsId` = I.Id;
```

When converted into JSON via PHP, it produces the following result:

```
[
 {
  "Id": "1",
  "Dish": "Baked Apple",
  "Ingredient": "Apple"
 },
 {
   "Id": "2",
   "Dish": "Seafood Rice Balls",
   "Ingredient": "Hylian Rice"
 },
 {
   "Id": "2",
   "Dish": "Seafood Rice Balls",
   "Ingredient": "Hyrule Bass"
 }
]
```

I need to somehow get it into this format:

```
[
 {
  "Id": "1",
  "Dish": "Baked Apple",
  "Ingredients": [
    {
     "Name": "Apple",
     "Id": "1"
    }
  ]
 },
 {
  "Id": "2",
  "Dish": "Seafood Rice Balls",
  "Ingredients": [
  {
   "Name": "Hylian Rice",
   "Id": 5
  },
  {
   "Name": "Hyrule Bass",
   "Id": 6
  }
  ]
 }
]
```

I'd also like to only really have 1 query, as this may get very large and I feel like running many queries is going to be slow

Also sorry if the syntax for the second JSON is incorrect, I manually typed that one in

Here's the PHP code I'm using:
[image: php code]

Comment: Post your actual code, not pictures of your code.

Comment: I don't think you can do it with a simple query! queries don't support this kinds of data structure. they simply return rows of data! what you want on the other hand is a very complex data structure!! there is arrays of objects stored inside a key called `ingredients`!

Comment: you're not far away. add the id to `$results[$row['id']]`, then check if this isset already. If yes, add the new ingredient, if not, push the whole array.

Comment: @JayBlanchard it was a lot to type in and i would have to space it out a hundred times to get it to register as code in stackoverflow. Maybe there is a trick, idk.

Comment: tip: paste it, then press Ctrl+K! This will indent the code

Comment: @Jeff so I would check to see if the food dish ID was set, if so, add the ingredient to a list?

Comment: @Jeff I didn't know you could do that lmao

Comment: @ChadK Yes. if so, do something like `$results[$row['id']]['ingredients'][] = [$iid, $iName]`

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = 'CALL GetAllDishIngredients()';
$data = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
$cnt = mysqli_num_rows($data);

$results = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
    $id = $row['Id'];
    $dishname = $row['Dish'];
    $ing = array();

    $ing[] = array(
        'Id' => $row['iId'],
        'IngredientName' => $row['Ingredient']
    );

    if(!isset($results[$id]))
    {
        $results[$id] = array(
          'Id' => $row['Id'],
          'Dish' => $row['Dish'],
          'Ingredients' => $ing
       );
    }
    else{
        array_push($results[$id]['Ingredients'], $ing[0]);
    }
}
$json = json_encode($results, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

That's how I ended up doing it. I used the isset variable to check to see if the Id already exists in the array. If it does, I use array_push to add the ingredient to the array.